# Compare Collection of Controls with a list

Tags: c#, list, controls

I have a FlowLayoutPanel, which I want to update with ProgressBars from a list of IDs (strings) and position of the current progressbars (integers). This List I'll call list **a**.

The `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` should be compared to the list **a**:

- If new IDs are detected, there should be created a new Control in
  the `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` collection with that ID (name).
- If a Control in the `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` collection doesn't have a corresponding name in the list **a**, it should be removed and disposed.
- Controls which are on both collections should be updated (Progress of the ProgressBar from an integer from list **a**)

What troubles me is that the `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` collection doesn't have as many methods as the generic list, and so I can't really follow any guides from the internet.

Can you help me how I should do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Reply to DJ KRAZE comment:
I have made something similar with lists, but as I said, Control collections don't have some of the methods as Lists does. Here is my code (May not work, I rewrote it to make it easier to understand):

**// Remove Old**

```
// Make a new list of IDs, where none of the IDs from myList1 can be found in myList2
var remove = myList1.Where(f => !myList2.Any(g => g == f.ID));

//Do some operation for the object which is about to get removed
foreach (Object obj in remove)
{
    // Some operation           
}
// remove from list
myList1.RemoveAll(i => remove.Contains(i));
```

**//Remove Duplicates**

```
// Remove Duplicates from myList2, so only the remaining object are to be started
myList2.RemoveAll(f => myList2.Any(g => g.ID == f));
```

**// Add remaining objects from myList2 to myList1**

```
foreach(Object obj in myList2)
{
// add to myList1 and do some operation, like starting it
}
```

Comment: what code do you have currently to show how you are trying to compare the collection items..?

Comment: #DJ KRAZE
I posted my old code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls collection of the `FlowLayoutPanel` (and of other container controls as well) does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` but only the non-generic `IEnumerable`. Therfore convert `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>` with the `Cast<T>` exension method. Then you can use all the plenty of LINQ:

```
 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls
     .Cast<Control>()
     .Where(c => c.Name == "...")
     .OrderBy(...)
     ...
```

Note: Most LINQ extension methods extend `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Let me just try it, and then I'll report back if it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Include `System.Linq` for all the extension methods.

Comment: I do have that included, but the Control collection still seems to have far less methods than generic list